# Why this code is returning wrong value? inputs= 5 ,{ -1,4,-6,7,-4}

Tags: c++, output, kadanes-algorithm

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        cin>>a[n];
    }                                       //array instillisation
    int cursum=0;
    int maxsum=INT_MIN;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
             cursum+=a[i];
             if(cursum<0){
                cursum=0;
             }
             maxsum=max(cursum,maxsum);
                }
      cout<<maxsum<<endl;               
      return 0; 
}
```

//this code is for  maximum subarray problem  using kadane's algo.My compiler is retrurning wrong output

Comment: Note that your code selects a null subarray if all values are negative, `max_sum= 0`

Comment: `int a[n]`, where `n` is a variable (value not known until run time) is not valid C++ (albeit it is a non-standard extension supported by some compilers).     Even ignoring that,  the first loop repeatedly reads a value to `a[n]`.   `a[n]` does not exist (it is past the end of the array `a`) so that loop has undfined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `cin` you are doing incorrect operation it should be

```
 cin>> a[i];
```

what you are doing is taking the value of a[n]